# How to scroll in a ScrollView using the scroller

Tags: android, scrollview

When I scroll a ScrollView I move the content up and down by touching and moving my finger up and down but instead this behavior I want to touch the ScrollView and when I move my finger down (the scroller moves down) the content of the ScrollView should move up. If I could drag the scroller and not the content of a ScrollView I will get the wanted result but how can I do that?

Comment: I think what you want is 'android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"' in your scrollview this will always show your scroll bar

Comment: no I don't want android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true". I want when I drag the scrollbar to top/up the content which is in scrollView moves down. For example in normal ScrollView in android the scrollbar is on top and I touch it up and the content moves up but I want the oposite behaviour when the scrollbar is on top and I drag it with my finger to bottom the content that is in scrollview should move up